# Which CP & CSC code choose to install stock rom Galaxy S3 i9300

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, device-firmware, odin, stock-rom, csc

I am installing stock rom because of get warranty back (now i am running Archidroid).

I don't know which firmware I should choose. My actual region code is **XEF** (stock recovery is saying that it's XEF. Archidroid is saying **I9300ARCHIDROIDARCHIDROID** but I live in Czech Republic so It should be **XEZ**. Than, I don't know which *CP* number i should choose.. My actual is **I9300XXUGNA8** which is *Uzbekistan or Kazakhstan* (wtf? :D).

What will happen when I flash stock firmware with **XEZ** (csc) and **I9300XXUGND5** (CP)? Thank you for your help. I am noob. I was googling and I found just what is AP, CP and CSC. But not what happen when I change it.

*I have international version of Galaxy S3 (GT-i9300)*

Thank you in advance

Comment: Any updates on this? I have a (CP) I9300XXUGNA8 here (UK Vodafone) I need to try and solve problems on by removing Lollipop. I'm downloading I9300XXUGNH4 to try.

Comment: Hi. u can use whatever version u want. All will work.